# Stream Android screencast to PC

Tags: android, stream

I'm going to make a presentation of an Android application, and since it will have a large audience assisting, I'll probably need to stream the Android screencast to a PC. Do you know any tool (free or paid) able to do it? Thank you.

Comment: You could always just run the app in the Emulator. This also came up on google straight away http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

Comment: I'm out of close votes for the day, but this is off-topic.

Comment: I don't agree, giving a presentation of an app in progress is a coding discussion.  Not to mention the mechanisms for doing so on android are not well developed.

Comment: This is not off topic. It can be used in programming scenarios also.

Comment: I don't think the Emulator will help me, since I need access to the wireless and the bluetooth adapter.
Thanks for the tip about AndroidScreencast, I'll try it. ;)

Comment: @Jems post an answer mate i think you are spot on.

Comment: I found a great too for this: http://blog.ribomation.com/2010/01/droidscreen/

Comment: The emulator is also hopeless for apps that use video.

Comment: many android devices supports TV out or HDMI out with just a cheap cable via USB/MHL, try to find an MHL cable for your device.

Comment: Yet another android screencast wrote in Qt https://github.com/yangh/sevensquare/tree/sevensquare-screencast

Comment: https://www.airdroid.com works well, juste did a demo with it

Comment: [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) is the every best tool I found!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found what I was looking for!

[**This tool**](http://droid-at-screen.org/) was written by someone who needed to do exactly what I need, and it work almost perfectly (I tried in Windows, but since it is Java should work on Linux too).

Comment: Looks interesting. For those interested there is a redirect on that page as they project has a new home: [http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/)

Comment: Tool is great, tried another 5 or 6, this one is the best no doubt, but do you know if there is another one a bit faster?

Comment: Sorry mate, this is the best I could find, unfortunately. :/

Answer (score 8):

The link posted by gnclmorais is broken. Here is the new one:

[Droid@Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/)

another userful tool is this:

[AndroidScreenCast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)

Comment: Thank you, I already fixed my link.

Comment: Droid@Screen link is broken

Comment: Updated Droid@Sceen link. Thanks RoboCop87