# Android record screen including audio

Tags: android, audio, video, screen-capture

I'm searching a tool or a method to record an Android App including Audio on a Android phone. On my research I found a similar question and three tools. But no one can't record video and audio together.

Similar question:

- [Stream Android screencast to PC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854220/stream-android-screencast-to-pc)

Tools:

- [AndroidScreenCast](http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/)
- [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/)
- [Android Screenshots and Screen Capture](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ashot/)

**Edit**

I found a app solution named [Screencast Video Recorder Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencastfree) which records video and audio. But you have to root the phone to use this app. Is there another possibility?

**Update February 2 2019**

I just stumbled over this developer android page called "[Record a video](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-video)" which seems to solve my question when using Android Studio:

> Logcat lets you record an MP4 video from your hardware device for a maximum of three minutes. You can, for example, use the video for your marketing materials or for debugging.
>
> 1. Open an app project.
> 2. [Run the app](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/index.html#RunningApp) on a hardware device.
> 3. Click **View > Tool Windows > Logcat.**
> 4. Interact with the display on the hardware device to stage the start of the video.
> 5. Click **Screen Record** in the left side of the Logcat window.
> 6. In the **Screen Recorder Options** dialog, set the recording options:
>
>    - **Bit Rate**: Enter a bit rate. The default is 4 Mbps.
>    - **Resolution**: Enter a width and height value in pixels. The value must be a multiple of 16. The default is the resolution of the device.
>    - **Show Taps**: Enables visual feedback for taps.
> 7. Click **Start Recording** to start the recording.
> 8. Click **Stop Recording** to stop the recording.
> 9. In the **Save As** dialog, save the MP4 file.
> 10. In the **Screen Recorder** dialog, click one of the buttons to show the file location, open the recording in a player, or dismiss the dialog.

Comment: What is the Android version you want that functionality working on? By the way, [Mobizen](https://www.mobizen.com) is for you! It is compatible from Android 4.4.4 for sure.

Comment: See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24200437/record-tablets-screen-and-audio/48097779#48097779

Comment: @noraj It's been a while since I asked this question, but thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no portable way of recording the audio that's being played on the phone. Unless you use the internal mic to record the sound coming from the internal loudspeaker, which A) will result in an extremely poor recording, and B) fails completely if the user has attached e.g. a wired headset.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would really be interesting how the big game developing companies do that: https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/ARCADE?feature=category-nav

Comment: @viperbone: Grab videos of their games with sound..? I don't know - but I know what I'd probably do: get a capture card / PVR with HDMI input and connect it to the phone's HDMI/MHL output.

Comment: Yes, grab videos of their games with sound. Ok, thanks I'll check that.