# Record tablet's screen AND audio

Tags: android, adb, screen-recording

I've been wondering, after trying this command on my Nexus 7:

```
adb shell screenrecord /sdcard/demo.mp4
```

Is there a way to record the screen AND audio of the tablet using the factory `screenrecord` command? Checking the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#screenrecord), it says nothing about recording the audio too, but we all know the Android documentation is not *that* complete

Comment: If you only want a screen record video -- try android screen cast.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I could do it this way :

- connect the Android device to computer with a jack cable (headphone output to microphone input);
- record video with adb shell;
- record audio with Audacity (or anything else)
- then merge video and audio with a video editor (pitivi, openshot, avconv...)

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a way using `screenrecord`. Looks like there is not a single one.

Answer (score 2):

Jeff's answer seems to be the only way you can use through adb. But that force you to do some work (merge video + audio).

Another way is to directly use an android app:

- SCR Screen Recorder - [official website](http://www.scr-screen-recorder.com/) - [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422061) - [short review](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/03/24/scr-screen-recorder-gets-experimental-support-for-internal-audio-recording-root-only/)
- Mobizen for SAMSUNG - [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rsupport.mobizen.sec&hl=fr)
- RecMe - [google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobzapp.recme.free&hl=fr)

**SCR Screen Recorder**:

- pros :

  - the only app that truly works for recording video + internal audio with all devices
- cons:

  - banned from google play because of SELinux policy (see [XDA -  Google Play ban and "Dangerous app" warning](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2422061))
  - require root for recording internal audio

**Mobizen for SAMSUNG**:

- pros

  - on google play store
- cons

  - only the samsung version works for recording internal audio, the general or LG, XIAOMI version can't record internal audio
  - still a beta feature
  - require root for recording internal audio

**RecMe**:

- pros

  - on google play store
- cons

  - internal audio recording doesn't works on most devices
  - require root for recording internal audio

Personally I tried a lot of apps and the only working for me is SCR Screen Recorder.

PS : all these apps works without root if not using internal audio.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no way to do it, according to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#screenrecord):

> **Note:** Audio is not recorded with the video file.